# Jquery - Ajax "too much recursion" errors showHide() and css.Fn

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Sorry for my english. I get the message of "too much recursion", and i think is in the ajax, here is the code:

```
function procesarPdf(carpeta,idRevista,dirarchivo,paginaProcesar,nombreArchivo){        
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'php/procesar_pdf.php',
                data:{carpeta:carpeta,revista:idRevista,archivo:dirarchivo,paginaProcesar:paginaProcesar,nombreArchivo:nombreArchivo},
                async:false,
                cache:false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var datos = data;           
                    if(datos.terminado==false){

                        procesarPdf(datos.carpeta,datos.idRevista,datos.archivo,datos.paginaAProcesar,datos.nombreArchivo);

                    } else {

                        alert("Finish process");
                        quitarEspera(); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I use pdf to process images to get images and thumbnails whit the file procesar_pdf.php.

When sucess i call again the function to continue the process and i use progressbar of jquery to see the progress, but when the progress is in 50% or 56% or 65%, the firebug throw me the message of "too much recursion" with other error how "css.Fn" or "showHide(this,arguments)".

I dont know the error, please tell me if know the error.

Comment: Very Thanks!!! work 100%

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function

```
procesarPdf(datos.carpeta,datos.idRevista,datos.archivo,datos.paginaAProcesar,datos.nombreArchivo);
```

from within the function `procesarPdf` - too much recursion would indicate that this is happening many times. Each time a function calls a function a new frame is added to the stack, and there is a limit to how deep the stack can be. You should pursue an alternate strategy for continuing the processing, especially if you want to do it synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it looks like you might be recursively calling the procesarPdf() too many times in whatever you are doing. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528183/jquery-javascript-error-too-much-recursion-with-self-calling-function) is a post that gets at the root of why another user was having a similar issue and getting the same error.