# Too Much Recursion When Dynamically Adding Click Event Listener With Post to a Div Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion, addeventlistener

I am getting 'too much recursion' errors with dynamically adding a click handler to div tags with a given class name ('reportLink' in this example) and cannot figure out what the issue is (scope issue?). The code works fine if I console.log the div's innerText, but fails when I add an ajax post to it. Does anyone see the issue here? Thank you for your help!

```
(function () {
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".reportLink");
const userName = document.getElementById("userName");

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    let link = links[i];
    createEvent(link);
}

function createEvent(element) {
    var etext = element.innerText;

    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'route/myroute',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { user: userName, reportName: etext },
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

})();

Comment: Maybe `user: userName` should be `user: userName.value`... not sure though

Comment: Not sure if it's similar (you don't have your function code in the success block...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640709/jquery-ajax-too-much-recursion-errors-showhide-and-css-fn

Comment: Guedes - I cannot believe I did that! After changing userName to userName.value it posted as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this syntax instead:

```
$("body").on("click", ".reportLink", function(e) {
    // Use $(this) for the element and get your other data..

    $.ajax({
        url: 'route/myroute',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { user: userName, reportName: etext },
        success: function (data) {
             //console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. `etext` should be `e.target.innerText` though.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! This shortened my code and worked as expected!